# Restangular.remove() Method DELETE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm trying to achieve DELETE Method using Restangular but it keeps giving the error Method DELETE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods.

Have goggled a lot but havent found a solution. Request works seamlessly with a POST MAN tho

```
var users = Restangular.all("users", userId);
                   return users.remove()
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response;
                });
```

By doing above Request Method is sent as OPTIONS , I think it should be DELETE

Answer (score 0):

I am also doing the something. Here is a solution:

You have to update in your api `web.config` file

```
<clear />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="OPTIONS,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE" />
```

In `ApiController`:

```
[HttpDelete]
public string Delete() 
{ 
    return "u call delete"; 
} 

public HttpResponseMessage Options() { 
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(); 
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK; 
    return response;
}
```

In Angular:

```
home.post().then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});

home.remove().then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Out Put...

```
> u call delete
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

i will post my code for my controller i hope it helps you
I use this controller with angularjs and django rest framework. In CategorySerializer i return pk and name

CategorySerializer:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('pk','name', 'owner','created')
```

in my cotroller.js file i have the code bellow to add a category and to delete a category :

```
appcontroller.controller('Route1Ctrl', function Route1Ctrl($scope,Restangular) {
  $scope.test = 'hello world !!!'
  $scope.name = '' 
  $scope.delete = function(pk) {
     Restangular.one('categories/',pk).remove().then(function() {
       var index = $scope.categories.indexOf(pk);
       if (index > -1) $scope.categories.splice(index, 1);
     });
  };
  Restangular.all('categories/').getList({}).then(function(data) {
   $scope.categories = data;
  });
  $scope.addCategory = function() {
    categories.post({'name':$scope.name})
  }
});
```